# JFrog Artifactory fails to connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: artifactory

I followed the following guides on installing JFrog Artifactory OSS using RPM/Yum and using an external PostgreSQL database.

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory
- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/PostgreSQL

SELinux is disabled and `jfrog-artifactory-oss` is installed from the JFrog repository [`https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-rpms`].

Check the service:

```
[root@jfrog ~]# systemctl status artifactory -l
● artifactory.service - Artifactory service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-08-08 01:56:50 +08; 11min ago
  Process: 9714 ExecStop=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10268 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12388 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
           ‣ 12388 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -server -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Djruby.bytecode.version=1.8 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dartdist=rpm -Djf.product.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory -Xms512m -Xmx3g -Djruby.bytecode.version=1.8 -Dartifactory.metadata.native.ui=true -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: 2020-08-07T17:56:50.027Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:462       ] [main] - Resolved shared.logging.consoleLog.enabled (true) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: JF_METADATA_ACCESSCLIENT_URL: http://localhost:8081/access
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: metadata started. PID: 12988
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog su[13048]: (to artifactory) root on none
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: Starting frontend...
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: frontend not running. Proceed to start it up.
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: 2020-08-07T17:56:50.317Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:462       ] [main] - Resolved shared.logging.consoleLog.enabled (true) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: frontend started. PID: 13147
Aug 08 01:56:50 jfrog systemd[1]: Started Artifactory service.
Aug 08 01:56:51 jfrog artifactoryManage.sh[10268]: 2020-08-07T17:56:51.003Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:462       ] [main] - Resolved shared.logging.consoleLog.enabled (true) from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
[root@jfrog ~]#
```

Test:

```
[root@jfrog ~]# curl -I http://localhost:8082/ui/
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 18:08:50 GMT
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

[root@jfrog ~]#
```

`/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log` shows the following errors:

```
[DEBUG] Resolved system configuration file path: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
No ssl parameter found, falling back to sslmode=disable
2020-08-07T17:56:50.179Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [1462831a45a25233] [database_bearer.go:84         ] [main                ] - Connecting to (db config: {postgresql user='jfroguser' password='***' dbname=jfrogdb host=dbserver.example.com port= sslmode=disable}) [database]
2020-08-07T17:56:50.216Z [jfmd ] [ERROR] [1462831a45a25233] [database_bearer.go:68         ] [main                ] - Could not initialize database (db config: {postgresql user='jfroguser' password='***' dbname=jfrogdb host=dbserver.example.com port= sslmode=disable}): error connecting to database
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.(*databaseBearer).init
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:114
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.NewDatabaseBearer
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:66
main.main
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/metadata.go:38
runtime.main
/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x38, 0xc00015c040, 0xc00032c080)
/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9d
jfrog.com/jfrog-go-commons/pkg/log.(*standardLogger).Panicfc(0xc00043bda0, 0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x13eb133, 0x32, 0xc00032c080, 0x2, 0x2)
/src/jfrog.com/go-commons/pkg/log/standard_logger.go:42 +0x6a
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.NewDatabaseBearer(0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x166f220, 0xc00007f770, 0x1673460, 0xc0000c97c0, 0x1666260, 0xc000011098, 0x16489c0, 0xc00043bd70, ...)
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:68 +0x2d4
main.main()
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/metadata.go:38 +0x5b7
[database]
panic: Could not initialize database (db config: {postgresql user='jfroguser' password='***' dbname=jfrogdb host=dbserver.example.com port= sslmode=disable}): error connecting to database
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.(*databaseBearer).init
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:114
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.NewDatabaseBearer
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:66
main.main
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/metadata.go:38
runtime.main
/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1373
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x38, 0xc00015c040, 0xc00032c080)
/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9d
jfrog.com/jfrog-go-commons/pkg/log.(*standardLogger).Panicfc(0xc00043bda0, 0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x13eb133, 0x32, 0xc00032c080, 0x2, 0x2)
/src/jfrog.com/go-commons/pkg/log/standard_logger.go:42 +0x6a
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.NewDatabaseBearer(0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x166f220, 0xc00007f770, 0x1673460, 0xc0000c97c0, 0x1666260, 0xc000011098, 0x16489c0, 0xc00043bd70, ...)
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:68 +0x2d4
main.main()
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/metadata.go:38 +0x5b7


goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/rs/zerolog.(*Logger).Panic.func1(0xc000358500, 0x4bb)
/pkg/mod/github.com/rs/zerolog@v1.18.0/log.go:338 +0x4f
github.com/rs/zerolog.(*Event).msg(0xc0000be240, 0xc000358500, 0x4bb)
/pkg/mod/github.com/rs/zerolog@v1.18.0/event.go:146 +0x200
github.com/rs/zerolog.(*Event).Msgf(0xc0000be240, 0xc000961dc0, 0x35, 0xc00015c0c0, 0x3, 0x4)
/pkg/mod/github.com/rs/zerolog@v1.18.0/event.go:126 +0x83
jfrog.com/jfrog-go-commons/pkg/log.(*standardLogger).logMessage(0xc00043bda0, 0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0xc0000be240, 0xc000961dc0, 0x35, 0xc00015c0c0, 0x3, 0x4)
/src/jfrog.com/go-commons/pkg/log/standard_logger.go:61 +0x197
jfrog.com/jfrog-go-commons/pkg/log.(*standardLogger).Panicfc(0xc00043bda0, 0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x13eb133, 0x32, 0xc00015c0c0, 0x3, 0x4)
/src/jfrog.com/go-commons/pkg/log/standard_logger.go:43 +0x1df
jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db.NewDatabaseBearer(0x166e420, 0xc000142750, 0x166f220, 0xc00007f770, 0x1673460, 0xc0000c97c0, 0x1666260, 0xc000011098, 0x16489c0, 0xc00043bd70, ...)
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/services/common/db/database_bearer.go:68 +0x2d4
main.main()
/src/jfrog.com/metadata/metadata.go:38 +0x5b7
```

Any ideas what to check? The server is an up-to-date Centos 7 server. Login to the external database is also possible:

```
[root@jfrog ~]# psql -h dbserver.example.com -p 5432 -U jfrog
Password for user jfrog:
psql (11.8)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

jfrog=> SHOW server_version;
 server_version
----------------
 11.8
(1 row)

jfrog=> \q
[root@jfrog ~]#
```

Comment: Can you try `http://localhost:8082/ui/ ` as recommended in the doc  you linked. If this does not work, please try `http://localhost:8082/router/api/v1/system/health`

Comment: @PrasannaRaghavendra thanks, that might have worked, but I proceeded with a next step, which is to use an external database (updated the whole thread).

Comment: Artifactory was able to connect to the database? Can  you share your system.yaml pls?

Comment: Seeing same issue on Artifactory 7.29.8. Getting "No ssl parameter found, falling back to sslmode=disable" in the logs. What's more is that the artifactory service updates its system.yaml on-the-fly and changes the password to some 95 char string (and then the connection fails since that string doesn't work). I wonder what's going on. My PG URL is just: url: "jdbc:postgresql://${ db_host }:5432/${ db_name }"

Comment: I misunderstood how the database.password field works in system.yaml. What happens is the password becomes a one way hash when specified in the explicit "password" field (as opposed to the insecure way to adding "?password=password" in the database.url field). This is expected and there's no issue here. The issue in my case is that I was missing "?sslmode=require" in database.url.